# Curious about adding classes and how to add them

Tags: python, class

So basically I'm just trying to make a simple coding thing in python that incorporates classes, user input user output, conditionals, loops and arrays and so far I have everything added but for classes and loops. And im sort of lost on how I would add a class to this code ive looked around on how to do classes but im still a little confused. here is my code for my current program. a quick little summary about it is that its basically just a barbershop and depending on the inputs and the lists it will give you a certain haircutl. I know its a little simple but I just started programming not to long ago.

```
print("Welcome to Sids Barbershop")
Question = input("Would you like to get your haircut today")
if(Question == "yes"):
    print ("Great come in and take a seat")
elif (Question == "no"):
    print("Sounds good come back when your ready")
mylist = [['boy','14','curly'],
          ['girl','12','straight'],
          ['Man','28','wavy'],
          ['Woman','26''curly']]
record = []
gender = input("Do you consider yourself a boy,girl, man or woman")
record.append(gender)

age = input("How old are you")
record.append(age)

hair = input("what kind of hair type do you have")
record.append(hair)


search = int(input('Select and index to search an entry:'))
print(mylist[search])
if (search == 0):
    print("alright so far so good would you like to get a fade and your hair cut by 2 inches?")
    



if(search == 1):
    print("Ok so you have straight hair would you just like a trim?")


if(search == 2):
    print("So you have wavy hair which is hard to deal with do you want to go bald?")


if(search == 3):
    print('ok you have super long and curly hair do you want to try something new and perm your hair straight?')
```

i have tried to look up what a class was and how to incorporate it but I'm not to sure on how to.

Answer (score 2):

A good use case for a class definition here would be the "customer" object that you're currently using the `list` class for.  You can simplify the class definition with the `@dataclass` decorator:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Customer:
    gender: str
    age: str
    hair: str
```

Then replace the lists in `mylist` with `Customer`s:

```
mylist = [
    Customer('boy','14','curly'),
    Customer('girl','12','straight'),
    Customer('Man','28','wavy'),
    Customer('Woman','26','curly'),
]
```

and define `record` as a `Customer` like this:

```
record = Customer(
    input("Do you consider yourself a boy,girl, man or woman"),
    input("How old are you"),
    input("what kind of hair type do you have"),
)
```

Whereas with a `list` you can only access elements by their numeric index, your new `Customer` class has named attributes -- instead of `record[1]` to get the age the user entered, you can do `record.age`, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help everything has worked out but for the list code you provided to me it says that it was not closed even though i used the brackets. Edit: sorry I just got it to work thanks so much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: I might recommend also defining a class method to wrap the three calls to `input` and subsequent instantiation of `Customer`.